# How to post source code

Tags: discussion

I was trying to post one of my source code  of a problem, but I was getting "not sufficient context provided." How do I remove that error?

Comment: Provide context. Explain your problem clearly with words.

Comment: thanks ,I think your answers is really helpful and it  makes me understand what I was missing. Thanks:)

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784113/forming-heap-using-array) then I think what people are saying is: you need to describe your problem. All you say is:

> I am trying to form a heap using the following code ,But not sure why its not showing the correct output

What *is* the correct output? What output is produced and why is it wrong? The comments are asking for more clarification on what you're trying to do.

If you're not talking about the comments, and are actually referring to a technical detail, **please edit your question and explain exactly what you did and what error message you received.**

Comment: Seems like his problem is that he doesn't know how to post code, though I'm not sure what that really means.

Comment: @LanceRoberts I don't either, the revision history shows he posted code just fine. I think he's talking about comments. But more clarification is needed either way.

Comment: got it thanks,actually when I posted the code ,that is the first time and am not aware about the extent of explanation required.But now I got that ,that I have got to explain each and every point before posting a question like that :)

Comment: What should I do if any of my question didn't get answered? How much time should I expect to get any question answered?

Comment: @NiteshNarayanLal None. You should not expect your question to be answered. SO is a free resource, but there is no guarantee that any question you ever ask would be answered. If you have edited your answer to provides updates on what you've done to fix it, posted a bounty etc and still don't have an answer, chances are no one knows how to solve the problem. The fact that you do get any answers altogether, is based on the ability of people understanding your problem, and then being able to fix it. The speed of this is dependent on the level of the people logged in at that point in time.